# SOLR Query with multible fields to search for

Tags: solr, solr4, solarium

i've build a query in solr that looks like this:

`https://local.solr.com/solr/select?omitHeader=true&wt=json&json.nl=flat&q=*:*&fq=xtitleLow_stringS:*1002*+OR+xartnumLow_stringS:*1002*`

I want to search in solr with the query "1002" for results. I didn't work it out how to search both fields with the normal query so i used the filter query.

But i can't boost the results so im kind of lost on this point. How to build this as a query so i can boost some of the fields?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the `edismax` handler provided by Solr. This allows to use list of fields to query. It has option to give separate weights for each of the field for scoring them differently.

```
defType=edismax&q=1002&qf=xtitleLow_stringS^20 xartnumLow_stringS
```

The above query will search for `1002` in each of the mentioned fields.
It will be also adding a boost of 20x to any hits in the `xtitleLow_stringS` field.

Please find the documentation link [here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#the-extended-dismax-query-parser) for more details